# Issue in char count in the textbox using Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html

What is the issue of this below code?

```
<textarea id="meta_title" name="meta_title" style="width:550px; height:50px;" onkeypress="document.getElementById(count_title).value=this.value.length;">Test Value</textarea>
<input type="text" style="width:30px" id="count_title" name="count_title" readonly="readonly" value=""/>
```

Comment: You are using inline style documentation btw, but where does your code go wrong ?

Comment: you should tell **us** what the issue is, so we can solve it (or at least give some hints). how shold anyone know what you're trying to do without at least a tiny bit of explanation?

Comment: the javascript console is your friend, it directly answers your question: `Cannot set property 'value' of null`, from which you could have deduced the problem yourself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you call getElementById with an empty variable called count_title:

```
document.getElementById(count_title).value
```

But you want to search for a string:

```
document.getElementById("count_title").value
```

Answer (score 1):

add `""` for `"count_title"`:

```
onkeypress='document.getElementById("count_title").value=this.value.length;'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the quotes around `count_title`, so this was treated as an uninitialized variable instead of a string.

Just add them and it works like intended like you can [see in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8aM3/).

(note that I also replaced your single quotes for double ones, as this is how most people do it)

Answer (score 1):

your onkeypress attribute had a syntax error , place double quotes in `document.getElementById("count_title")......`

```
onkeypress='document.getElementById("count_title").value=this.value.length;'>Test 

Value</textarea>&nbsp;
<input type='text' style='width:30px' id='count_title' name='count_title' 

readonly='readonly' value=""/>
```